# Use MPMoviePlayerController UI with LibVLC

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, libvlc

Is it possible to use the standard iOS video player UI from MPMoviePlayerController with LibVLC? What I want is the standard UI from iOS with the technology from LibVLC (because I need to work with FLV video).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because the standard UI is part of the view controller and an implementation detail subject to change anytime (remember the complete visual change from iOS 6 to 7), so it is not publicly available.

To use VLCKit in your app, you need to do your own UI implementation. However, VLCKit includes sample code for iOS, which allows you to do this quite easily.